# Is it possible to add a description or help text to an aspect's property in Alfresco Share?

Tags: alfresco

Is it possible to add a description or help text to an aspect's property in Alfresco Share? I cannot change the title because it would require too much text.

Comment: A custom aspect of yours, or a regular built-in Alfresco one?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly where you'd want the property description to show up in Share?

Comment: Also, did you try setting both a *<title>...</title>* and a *<description>...</description>* on the aspect property definition?

Comment: Yep, that was the answer. I'm surprised that tag wasn't mentioned in the docs I was using. You want to re-enter that so I can give you credit?

Comment: Were you using some documentation from alfresco.com, or third party information? If the former, I'd be interested to know which one you used that was missing it

Comment: Both. The Alfresco documentation, online and in books, read more like random notes a developer would keep in his engineering notebook than actual documentation. To many examples are incomplete, often just saying something is possible, and none of them offer the detail   needed for true understanding. They really need to hire a technical writer with no prior knowledge of the product and a willingness to make the developers explain everything.

Comment: Alfresco has a number of wonderful technical writers, but they can't write about everything all the time! It might be worth opening a documentation bug in the [Alfresco Issue Tracker](http://issues.alfresco.com/) to let them know it's an area that would benefit from some more time when they have the chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining your type or aspect, you can set both a title and description. These will generally be shown in Forms, in Share and Explorer, and are normally the easiest way to explain to both users and developers about your model.

To see this in use, take a look at the **audio:audio** aspect in Alfresco, the latest version is [available here](http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/repository/config/alfresco/model/contentModel.xml). You'll see some of the aspect properties have both a title and a description. If you upload an MP3 into Alfresco 4, and edit the metadata for it in Share, you should see that information show up.

As a general guide though, your aspect should look something like:

```
 <aspect name="test:thing">
     <title>Testing Content</title>
     <description>Aspect applied to mark content as being for testing use</description>
     <properties>
        <property name="test:edition">
           <title>Test Edition</title>
           <description>Which testing edition does this belong to?</description>
           <type>d:int</type>
        </property>
        <property name="test:notes">
           <title>Test Notes</title>
           <description>Notes for using this content in testing</description>
           <type>d:text</type>
        </property>
     </properties>
  </aspect>
```

If you're going to be using your type or aspect in a multi-lingual system, then you should look at the [Model Localisation Guide](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide#Model_Localization) for information on how to specify names, titles and descriptions from properties bundles which can be localised